2007 chevy malibu ls. 2.2l v6
I have a 2007 Chevrolet Malibu today I was trying to replace the radio and the remote turn on wire did not work so Google told me I could wire it to a fuse in the fuse panel I did that but the positive or negative wire touch something or one another and shorted something out not exactly sure if that's what's wrong but I'm 17 and have no clue what to fix or what to look at everything was fine and working until I heard and seen the spark. What's happening now is there's no power to anything no lights on the instrument panel no electrical at all to any parts of the car hooked up a battery jumper and the battery is completely fine with voltage and health not sure what could be wrong but im so desprate for a lead in the right direction

You trusted Google?  Did you know whether you were handling a +ve or -ve wire when it touched something?  Have you checked all the fuses?

Yeah i know i thought it was scetch i connected the wire to a 10 amp fuse in the inside fuse box for the roof and heated seat and connected it it the radio on switch so when the key is turned the radio turns on but i thing the ground and positive wire where touching and i think i fried something

I checked the fuses under the hood and a 30 and a 50 where clearly blown it was dark so i didnt see it before hopefully thats my issue
